# How do I work around Moq SetupSequence.Throws missing the lazy eval overloads that pass in the original called-setup args

Tags: c#, moq

SetupSequence(...).Throws is missing a lot of overloads that Setup(...).Throws has.

Setup.Throws has a whole family of overloads for receiving the original args to the called setup:

```
IThrowsResult Throws<T, TException>(Func<T1, T2, ..., TException> exceptionFunction) where TException : Exception;
```

SetupSequence.Throws has **no** overloads that recieve the original args to the called setup, just a non-receiving delegate that can only fabricate info unrelated to the args to the call:

```
ISetupSequentialResult<TResult> Throws<TException>(Func<TException> exceptionFunction) where TException : Exception;
```

I have cases where I need to setup sequences (and want to stay within the bounds of the MoQ-provided SetupSequence mechanism and not roll my own handling loops and such), and where

- the .Returns or .Throws both need the context of the called arg values
- I need to perform logic in the delegate. not just return the exception (like if I want a Task.Delay before it pretends to throw the exception). I don't just want to simulate a .Throw, I want a .Throw that took N millis before it threw.
- I need CancellationToken propagation to come from the "real" one in the caller args.

Imagine the first example given in https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/573, but with this for the .Throws

```
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.DoSomething(/* a verbose list of argument matchers here */))
    .Returns(1)
    .Returns(42)
    .Returns((a, b, c) => CalculateSomeSpecialValueFromArgs(a, b))
    //.Throws(new Exception("y"))
    .Throws(async(a, b, c, delay, ct) => {
        await Task.Delay(delay, ct);
        return new Exception($"{a} {b} {c} failed");
    })
    .Returns(72);
    ...
```

Things I tried/looked into:

1. Fabricate a Func (the closest overload to what I wish it had; at least its a delegate), but that can't work as I can't create a delegate ahead of time that has the called arg values.
2. Using .Callback doesn't help because while it can receive the called arg values, it has no way to influence MoQ's .Throw with them.
3. Nothing besides passing along the original called values will help the CancellationToken usage which I also need to honor.

How can I do what I am trying to do?